# display array data through map in react table

Tags: json, reactjs, dictionary

[image: WHAT I WANNA DISPLAY]I am trying to display array data in a table for my react app. Every time i reference the data in the table cells in returns the same element for all the columns. I would like to display each of the dates in each column.[image: ![Table displaying incorrectly]

My Table:

```
function SomeComponenet(props) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {props.attendence.map.forEach((attendence, index) => {
        return (
          <Paper>
            <Table aria-label="simple table">
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>Name</TableCell>

                  <TableCell align="right">
                    {attendence.Attendence[index].date}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">
                    {attendence.Attendence[index].date}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">
                    {attendence.Attendence[index].date}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">
                    {attendence.Attendence[index].date}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">
                    {attendence.Attendence[index].date}
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
            </Table>
          </Paper>
        );
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

My data:

```
const fakeData = [
  {
    Name: "A Person",
    Attendence: [
      {
        date: "2019/12/01",
        attendence: 1
      },
      {
        date: "2019/12/02",
        attendence: 1
      },
      {
        date: "2019/12/03",
        attendence: 1
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: you are using the same index value, you need to increment the index. 

PS: You need to use a better approach to iterate through the map also. React has much better ways to handle it.

Comment: I don't increment index because I do not want to hard code index for every element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need another map inside the {props.attendence.map}

link to codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-grass-sg5hr

```js
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Table } from "reactstrap";

function Test() {
  const attendence = [
    {
      Name: "A Person",
      Attendence: [
        {
          date: "2019/12/01",
          attendence: 1
        },
        {
          date: "2019/12/02",
          attendence: 1
        },
        {
          date: "2019/12/03",
          attendence: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {attendence.map(person => {
        return (
          <Table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                {person.Attendence.map(personAttendendance => {
                  return <th>{personAttendendance.date}</th>;
                })}
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{person.Name}</td>
                {person.Attendence.map(personAttendendance => {
                  return <td>{personAttendendance.attendence}</td>;
                })}
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        );
      })}
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: How do you want the table to display?

Comment: @ user2957033  : 2019/12/01    2019/12/02   2019/12/03   and the attendance for each of the dates in the rows beneath them.  I can only get that if I hard code the indexes and that is not ideal

Comment: So just like in the codesandbox I've added above? or do you want all the dates inside one <td> ?

Comment: Do you have a wireframe or screenshot of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: user2957033, I added the screenshot to my original question of how the table should display. I had to hard code the indexes like : attendence.Attendence[0].date to get that to display but I am hoping there is a way to avoid that

Comment: Look at the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-grass-sg5hr. Is this how it should look? If so look at test.js in the codesandbox and replace the th with TableHead and td with TableCell

Comment: Yes, that's how it should look

Comment: I just implemented your solution. I works great. Thank youuu sooooo much

Answer (score 0):

that's because all the indexes are the same in one iteration of the topper map. you can't use forEach on a map this way.

you can remove forEach and do another map on attendence.Attendence
something like this:

```
function SomeComponenet(props) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    {props.attendence.map((attendence, index) =>{
        {console.log(attendence.Attendence)}
        return( 
        <Paper >
          <Table aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                {attendence.Attendence.map( newAttendence => {
                 return(
                <TableCell align="right">
                   {newAttendence.date}
                </TableCell>
               )
               })}

              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
           </Table>
       </Paper>
            );
        })}
    </ReactFragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: I have tried to map through the first map but then each date is display in every column throughout each row as if I am saying the rows should repeat or something

Comment: If i do the second map inside the first then I get the dates in repeating rows like this:  2009/12/01   2019/12/01   2019/12/01 and the second row displays the second date just like this. I want the dates to be at the top of the columns not in every row